# MVC3 LowerCase route value behaves differently from UpperCase?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, enums, radio-button, html-helper

Apologies for lots of code in here...I've tried to keep it as short as possible:

I have written (stolen mostly from here) a HtmlHelper extension to write out a RadioButton (grouped) based upon an enum.  I have also set my route map so it uses an enum instead of "id" etc.

I have two enum's (for this example) CurrencyType and StatusType

When I call the URL /GBP/Open, my HtmlHelper works correctly and sets the value of the radio buttons with GBP and Open checked.

When I call the URL /gbp/open - the Helper still checks the values and appears to work...but when RadioButton().ToHtmlString() is called the "checked" is not present????
With the default routing in place, the radio buttons are still set correctly too???

If you breakpoint the returned SelectList then you can see the option selected is set correctly, so I'm a little stumped as to where the problem is arising?

---

```
Empty MVC3 website called Area36...Area 51 was taken ;)


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;

namespace Area36.Models
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum enumObj)
        {
            var values = from TEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
                         select new { ID = e, Name = e };
            return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name", enumObj);
        }

        public static void AppendFormatLine(this StringBuilder sb, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat(format, args);
            sb.AppendLine();
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonForEnum<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string fieldSet)
        {
            var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
            var e = (TProperty)Enum.Parse(typeof(TProperty), metaData.Model.ToString());
            var selectList = e.ToSelectList();
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            if (selectList != null)
            {
                sb.AppendFormatLine("<fieldset><legend>{0}</legend>", fieldSet);
                foreach (SelectListItem item in selectList)
                {
                    var id = string.Format("{0}_{1}", metaData.PropertyName, item.Value);
                    if (htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix != string.Empty)
                        id.Insert(0, string.Format("{0}_", htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix));

                    var label = htmlHelper.Label(id, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Text));
                    var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButton(name: metaData.PropertyName, value: item.Value, isChecked: item.Selected, htmlAttributes: new { id = id }).ToHtmlString();

                    sb.AppendFormatLine("<div class=\"radio_{0}\">{1}{2}</div>", metaData.PropertyName, radio, label);
                }
                sb.AppendLine("</fieldset>");
            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Area36.Models;

namespace Area36.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index(CurrencyType currency, StatusType status)
        {
            return View(new ViewModel { Currency = currency, Status = status });
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Area36.Models
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public CurrencyType Currency { get; set; }
        public StatusType Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
@using Area36.Models
@model Area36.Models.ViewModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@Html.RadioButtonForEnum(m => m.Currency, "Currency")
@Html.RadioButtonForEnum(m => m.Status, "Status")
```

---

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{currency}/{status}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", currency = CurrencyType.EUR, status = StatusType.Closed} // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried various options to solve this. Passed UpperCase values forcefully. Most surprisingly when I passed 'true' for all the radio buttons as follows, even then the output was same, buttons were checked only for uppercase url.

```
var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButton(metaData.PropertyName, item.Value, true, new { id = id }).ToHtmlString();
```

With some rnd with this code and some googling I found [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1338576.aspx).
If you check 
Following is code from MVC3-rtm. Here you can see value of isChecked is modified depending on ModelState and if you check the value of modelState.Values[index].AttemptedValue in debug mode, it is obviously in lowercase (for "gbp/open"). That's why lowercase url doesn't render checked attribute.

```
private IHtmlString BuildRadioButton(string name, object value, bool? isChecked, IDictionary<string, object> attributes) {
        string valueString = ConvertTo(value, typeof(string)) as string;

        TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("input");
        builder.MergeAttribute("type", "radio", true);
        builder.GenerateId(name);
        builder.MergeAttributes(attributes, replaceExisting: true);

        builder.MergeAttribute("value", valueString, replaceExisting: true);
        builder.MergeAttribute("name", name, replaceExisting: true);

        var modelState = ModelState[name];
        string modelValue = null;
        if (modelState != null) {
            modelValue = ConvertTo(modelState.Value, typeof(string)) as string;
            isChecked = isChecked ?? String.Equals(modelValue, valueString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }

        if (isChecked.HasValue) {
            // Overrides attribute values
            if (isChecked.Value) {
                builder.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked", true);
            }
            else {
                builder.Attributes.Remove("checked");
            }
        }

        AddErrorClass(builder, name);

        return builder.ToHtmlString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you :)  With this knowledge, I've added a check on the resulting string and if the item is checked but doesn't contain "checked=checked" then I manually add it.